# Detect when a webhost is posted to?

Tags: php, html, c++

I am trying to learn PHP and HTML in order to do something for my program. I'm trying to make a whitelist for my C++ application by sending a request to a webhost, and if the username and password provided is on the MySQL database it'll echo true. I've got this working completely, however my code right now just has a variable which is the username and password, so you can't actually do anything unless you are able to edit the code to the webhost, but I'd like to have it automatic because I wouldn't want to check the webhost every time a user tries to login.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I guess you need something like http://www.php-cpp.com

Comment: I just want to send a request to the webserver. I've seen it done before but can't think of how.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. Are you writing a C++ application that acts like a web client? What do you mean by "detect when a webhost is posted to"? Are you trying to intercept when the user is using their normal browser?

Answer (score 0):

PHP stores post in the superglobal `$_POST`

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    //Post variables exist
    //Do any stat checking here, or handle the post however needed
} else {
    //No post variables
}
```

Comment: How would I access whatever is posted?

Comment: `$_POST['keyname']`, with keys corresponding to the name of the input field in your markup. If you aren't sure what they are, use `var_dump($_POST);` or `var_dump(array_keys($_POST));`

Comment: I admit I don't really understand the question, but it looks to me like he's asking how to do something in his C++ client application, not how to process parameters in the PHP server script.

Comment: But if your interpretation of the question is correct, the simple answer is something like `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`. Form processing should be explained in just about any PHP tutorial.

Comment: If the form is being processed in the C++ side, take a look here: https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/07/introduction-to-c-cgi-processing-forms/

Comment: I tried echo var_dump(array_keys($_POST)); and it put "array(0) { }"

Comment: That means you have nothing that was posted